# Bad performance in a 99% read-only NHibernate web application

Tags: performance, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am currently investigating a ASP.NET MVC web application which is reported to have poor performance under load. (But load is only a few requests per second).

We are using MySQL + NHibernate + Castle ActiveRecord for the mapping. A NHibernate session is opened at the beginning of every session and kept open in view.

I already optimized the data access pattern to avoid Select N+1 problems where possible.

Now what I'm thinking about is.. on each request a database transaction is opened and commited at the end. And in 99% of our requests (MVC actions) no data has to be written to the database.

1. Is it possible and do you see benefit in closing sessions/transactions earlier or even mark sessions as read-only?
2. Could database locking be a bottleneck and if so is it possible to explicitly avoid locking at least for the read-only transactions?

Comment: Please check if you by any chance create a sessionfactory for each session. Creating the sessionfactory is quite expensive and should be done once upon application startup or first request. After that it can be used for any number of sessions.

Comment: Without profiling data, any answers provided will be guesswork.

Answer (score 6):

You should verify that your application is not loading huge amount of data from DB. Even with all select n+1 resolved you can load millions of records and it is going to be very slow.

Verify your pages with [NHibernate profiler](http://nhprof.com/). It will come up with optimization suggestions. If not, probably NH is not your bottleneck.

Comment: Agreed. Give NHibernate profiler a shot. You'll be surprised with the stuff that it finds

Comment: Okay, we have already been using NHibernate profiler in a test-system (it pointed us to the N+1 problems). Maybe it shows other results in the live system.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have few requests per second, then the overhead of opening transactions is not the reason for the poor performance. Try to let NHibernate log all the SQL that is sent to the server. This can give you some idea of why the thing i slow. Probably it is sending a billion queries for each HTTP request or else some well-chosen indices on your tables could probably help you.

Comment: I already checked this with NHibernate profiler. We had up to 25 requests per session (which is not good but should not take up to 5 seconds). If you see no optimization potential in the transactions, I have to check other possibilities..

Comment: The overhead for 25 requests is negligible, so you should spend your time finding out why the requests themselves take so long. Take each of them and run them on the database to which of them take too much time.